# Setting Background via a function breaks ControlTemplate triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

C#:

```
private void SW_btnMouseOverHighlight(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Type type = sender.GetType();
            PropertyInfo bgColor = type.GetProperty("Background");
            if (bgColor != null)
            {
                String color = bgColor.GetValue(sender).ToString();
                Color col = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color);
                col.R += ShipWeaponUIConstants.mouseOverHighlightIntensity;
                col.G += ShipWeaponUIConstants.mouseOverHighlightIntensity;
                col.B += ShipWeaponUIConstants.mouseOverHighlightIntensity;
                var brush = new SolidColorBrush(col);
                //bgColor.SetValue(sender, brush);
            }
        }
```

xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonColor}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="SW_btnMouseOverHighlight"/>
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="SW_btnMouseOverHighlightRemove"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger  Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF45B62C"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF222222"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="borderLight" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF333333"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="borderDark" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF777777"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So i have a toggle button. It's background changes color when its checked. (via the trigger in the xaml)
I also have a C# function that takes the color of the button and brightens it to show that the mouse is over it.

Both features work fine on their own, but when I enable both of them, then the colorchange in the C# function overrides any subsequent colorchanges via the xaml triggers.

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly because a local value (set by `SetValue` in the property setter) has higher [value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) than a value from a Style Setter.

Try `DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue` instead. You should also get the property value by `DependencyObject.GetValue` instead of reflection.

```
private void SW_btnMouseOverHighlight(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = (DependencyObject)sender;
    var background = obj.GetValue(Control.BackgroundProperty) as SolidColorBrush;

    if (background != null)
    {
        var color = background.Color;
        ...
        obj.SetCurrentValue(Control.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(color));
    }
}
```